# Link external C++ External C++ In the Main file?

Tags: c++

I want to make my code into multiple C++ files.

Here is an example of what I mean:

1. main.cpp holds basic layout
2. player.cpp holds how the character moves
3. bg.cpp holds the background and attachments

I want to join all of the code from these files together in main.cpp.

Like in C, you can link external files using include like so

```
#include 'file.c'
```

Is there anyway I can do this in C++ too? Is it the same way or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You should not be including `*.c` or `*.cpp` files.  The typical convention is to use header files (`*.h`, `*.hpp`, etc.)  However, yes, preprocessor includes behave the same way as in C, so anything you have learned there should also apply to C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#include` directive works the same in C and in C++ compiler: It literally pastes the text of the specified file instead of where the directive is located, as though you had performed a copy-and-paste of its contents. So, yes, you could write `#include player.cpp` within `main.cpp`.

However - this is discouraged and very rarely practiced.

First, the accepted convention is that files you include elsewhere are referred to as "header files", and give the suffix `.h`, `.hpp` or `.hxx`.

More significantly, it is almost universal practice, both when writing C code and when writing C++ code, to break up your code not just into *files*, but into different "translation units" - different pieces of code compiled separately. Each translation unit only needs to include headers which *declare* the functions it depends upon (in addition to type definitions etc.) - while the implementations can be left to separate `.cpp` files which don't include each other.

So, in your example, you may have a `.hpp` file for `player.cpp` and for `bg.cpp`; and `main.cpp` will include `player.hpp` and `bg.hpp`, since it probably calls functions from the two other files. You would compile the 3 translation units into `main.o`, `bg.o` and `player.o`; and finally, you'll link three compiled objects into a single executable.

For more details on how that happens you should consult online tutorials or introductory textbooks on C++ software development.

Comment: I get what your saying, but how would I get the .h, .hpp, and .hxx? Would I just rename the file extension from cpp to hpp or is there more to it?

Comment: @Nooby427: No, you separate your code into declarations, type definitions, enum definitions etc - that goes into the header. The actual implementations - function definitions - go into the `.cpp`. That's only a rough, partial characterization though, which ignores issues like templates, static functions and so on.